# How to inherit a style with React/Styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Im trying to make a component which wraps around some component and adds an animation delay to the content, This is working fine BUT the styles are not inherited from the code that is inside of it. Heres my code so far:

How the component will be called:

```
 <Type>
    <h1>Title for me</h1>
 </Type>
```

Code that it calls:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import useTypewriter from 'components/functions/useTypewriter'

export default function Type(props) {
  const content = props.children.props.children
  console.log(props.chilren);
  const [effectContent, startEffect] = useTypewriter(content,20)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      startEffect()
    },200)
  })
  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Hidden>{props.children}</Hidden>
      <OriginalStylePlease>{effectContent}</OriginalStylePlease>
    </Wrap>

  )
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;
const Hidden = styled.div`
  visibility: hidden;
`;

const OriginalStylePlease = styled.h1`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
`;
```

As you might already be able to tell, I am just taking this content from the child and then putting it inside of a div which is not what i wanted to do.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want? Can u add 'labels' or comments to your code to tell us what went wrong?

Comment: From the type function i would like to return the same component as was passed to it ( props.children ) but with altered text content

Comment: props.children = <h1>title</h1>   .... okay then what do u want to do with this? You just want the "Title For Me" text?

Comment: I want to return this but with some altered text - So the 'effectContent' is just a string state which delays each letter being added, So i want to return the children (child) of this <Type> component but with altered text content

Comment: Yes but with the same styles as it originally had

Comment: that's not how u use props.children, props.children just contain everything. don't put the <h1> tag. put <h1> tag around affectcontent

Comment: I know i could do that, But i want this to be able to be used across the site. Is there anyway to do this where the interface would be <Type> <p> hi </p> </Type>?

Comment: Hi, I just posted my own solution ir your interested

Answer (score 0):

This was the final component - it uses the CSS property 'all'

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import useTypewriter from 'components/functions/useTypewriter'

export default function Type(props) {
  const content = props.children
  const [effectContent, startEffect] = useTypewriter(content,100)
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      startEffect()
    },props.delay)
  })
  return (
    <Wrap>
      <Hidden>{content}</Hidden>
      <Original>{effectContent}</Original>
    </Wrap>

  )
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  all: inherit;
  position: relative;
  color: inherit;
`;
const Hidden = styled.div`
  all: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;

`;

const Original = styled.h1`
  all: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
`;
```